# Combine: rowwise(), mutate(), across(), for multiple functions

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise, across

This is somehow related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67347128/rownames-to-column-does-not-work-after-rowwise-properly/67347175#67347175):
In principle I try to understand how `rowwise` operations with `mutate` across multiple columns applying more then 1 functions like (`mean()`, `sum()`, `min()` etc..) work.

I have learned that `across` does this job and not `c_across`.
I have learned that the function `mean()` is different to the function `min()` in that way that `mean()` doesn't work on dataframes and we need to change it to vector which can be done with unlist or as.matrix -> learned from Ronak Shah [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282839/understanding-rowwise-and-c-across)[Understanding rowwise() and c_across()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282839/understanding-rowwise-and-c-across)

Now with my actual case: I was able to do this task but I loose one column `d`. How can I avoid the loose of the column `d` in this setting.

My df:

```
df <- structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15, d = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e"), e = 1:5), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Works not:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(a:e), 
         avg = mean(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE),
         min = min(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE), 
         max = max(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE)
  )

# Output:
      a     b     c d         e   avg min   max  
  <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1     6    11 a         1    NA 1     a    
2     2     7    12 b         2    NA 12    b    
3     3     8    13 c         3    NA 13    c    
4     4     9    14 d         4    NA 14    d    
5     5    10    15 e         5    NA 10    e
```

Works, but I loose column `d`:

```
df %>% 
  select(-d) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(a:e), 
         avg = mean(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE),
         min = min(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE), 
         max = max(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE)
  )

      a     b     c     e   avg   min   max
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6    11     1  4.75     1    11
2     2     7    12     2  5.75     2    12
3     3     8    13     3  6.75     3    13
4     4     9    14     4  7.75     4    14
5     5    10    15     5  8.75     5    15
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `pmap()` from `purrr` might be more preferable since you need to select the data just once and you can use the select helpers:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(pmap_dfr(across(where(is.numeric)),
                 ~ data.frame(max = max(c(...)),
                              min = min(c(...)),
                              avg = mean(c(...)))))

      a     b     c d         e   max   min   avg
  <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     6    11 a         1    11     1  4.75
2     2     7    12 b         2    12     2  5.75
3     3     8    13 c         3    13     3  6.75
4     4     9    14 d         4    14     4  7.75
5     5    10    15 e         5    15     5  8.75
```

Or with the addition of `tidyr`:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(res = pmap(across(where(is.numeric)),
                   ~ list(max = max(c(...)),
                          min = min(c(...)),
                          avg = mean(c(...))))) %>%
 unnest_wider(res)
```

Comment: Thank you tmfmnk. Could you please shortly comment on `c(...)`.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106591/why-ellipsis-have-to-be-wrapped-inside-c-when-used-in-lambda-functions-in) question.  This may help

Comment: If usage of `purrr` is okay, nothing better than this.  +1.

Comment: @TarJae These two might also help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049561/using-pmap-with-c-part-2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037099/using-pmap-function-to-check-whether-all-values-in-a-row-are-positive-or-negativ

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**

Best way out here

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(min = min(c_across(a:e & where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE),
         max = max(c_across(a:e & where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE), 
         avg = mean(c_across(a:e & where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE)
  )

# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c d         e   min   max   avg
  <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     6    11 a         1     1    11  4.75
2     2     7    12 b         2     2    12  5.75
3     3     8    13 c         3     3    13  6.75
4     4     9    14 d         4     4    14  7.75
5     5    10    15 e         5     5    15  8.75
```

**Earlier Answer**
Your `this will work` won't even work properly, if you change the output sequence, see

```
df %>% 
  select(-d) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(a:e), 
         min = min(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE),
         max = max(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE), 
         avg = mean(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm = TRUE)
  )

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c     e   min   max   avg
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     6    11     1     1    11  5.17
2     2     7    12     2     2    12  6.17
3     3     8    13     3     3    13  7.17
4     4     9    14     4     4    14  8.17
5     5    10    15     5     5    15  9.17
```

Therefore, it is advised to do it like this-

```
df %>% 
  select(-d) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(min = min(c_across(a:e), na.rm = TRUE),
         max = max(c_across(a:e), na.rm = TRUE), 
         avg = mean(c_across(a:e), na.rm = TRUE)
  )

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c     e   min   max   avg
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     6    11     1     1    11  4.75
2     2     7    12     2     2    12  5.75
3     3     8    13     3     3    13  6.75
4     4     9    14     4     4    14  7.75
5     5    10    15     5     5    15  8.75
```

One more alternative is

```
cols <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'e')
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(min = min(c_across(cols), na.rm = TRUE),
         max = max(c_across(cols), na.rm = TRUE), 
         avg = mean(c_across(cols), na.rm = TRUE)
  )

# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c d         e   min   max   avg
  <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     6    11 a         1     1    11  4.75
2     2     7    12 b         2     2    12  5.75
3     3     8    13 c         3     3    13  6.75
4     4     9    14 d         4     4    14  7.75
5     5    10    15 e         5     5    15  8.75
```

Even @Sinh suggested approach of group_by won't work properly in these cases.

Comment: Thank you very much AnilGoyal. I really appreciate your efforts and I understand all your thoughts and agree with you. But somehow I am not satisfied to repeat `c_across(a:e & where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE)` three times. I imagine that it should be possible to prevent this repetition and use it once with `across`.

Comment: TarJae, I fear what you are trying to do with `dplyr` only may not be possible, `mutate(across..` works in slightly different way.  It mutates all the existing columns in it.  Even if you use `cur_data` it will include newly added columns as shown above.  Moreover, you still have to repeat `cur_data..bla..bla` again n number of times unlike `mutate(across`.  This may however, be possible with many methods in `purrr` - one as shown in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method which would preserve the `data.frame` attribute in `mutate` if we want to set a particular column to row name attribute (`column_to_rownames`) and then return the attribute after the transformation

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   column_to_rownames('d') %>%
   mutate(max = reduce(., pmax), min = reduce(., pmin), 
         avg = rowMeans(.)) %>% 
   rownames_to_column('d')
#  d a  b  c e max min  avg
#1 a 1  6 11 1  11   1 4.75
#2 b 2  7 12 2  12   2 5.75
#3 c 3  8 13 3  13   3 6.75
#4 d 4  9 14 4  14   4 7.75
#5 e 5 10 15 5  15   5 8.75
```

Comment: Dear Arun, is it possible to apply all three function on each row using `invoke_map` or `exec`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also included `mean` into the function list but since it is a column-wise operation it wouldn't get to the desired result. However `pmin` and `pmax` make it possible to get the max and min per rows because of their functionality. I was just curious.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR the functions `pmin/pmax` and `mean` have different behavior.  pmin/pmax acts on the rows in a parallel, where as `mean` expects a vector and it is not vectorized. You may expect `rowMeans` to work, but the arguments to that function is just a single one i.e. `x` which can be matrix or data.frame/tibble.  where as in `pmax/pmin`, it is `...` ie. it can vary.  So `invoke_map(list(pmax, pmin),  list(df %>% select(-d)))` works as the arguments are are the data.frame columns

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. That argument matching is an important factor which I need to take into account in a moment like this. But glad to have finally familiarized myself with parallel maxima and minima.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a row-wise tibble column creates a readable, elegant solution. The `mean` function takes a bit of extra work since it does not accept values with the ellipsis (`...`):

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(x = pick(where(is.numeric)),
         avg = mean(unlist(x)),
         min = min(x),
         max = max(x)) |>
  select(-x) |>
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
      a     b     c d         e   avg   min   max
  <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11 a         1  4.75     1    11
2     2     7    12 b         2  5.75     2    12
3     3     8    13 c         3  6.75     3    13
4     4     9    14 d         4  7.75     4    14
5     5    10    15 e         5  8.75     5    15
```